# python pandas : how to get the primary key after unstack()

Tags: python, pandas

when you run a groupby and then unstack():

```
a.groupby(['date', 'secondaryKey']).aggregate({'clients':sum}).unstack()
```

you normally get something like this:

```
secondaryKey  E1.0  E2.0  E3.0  E4.0  E5.0  E6.0  E7.0  E8.0  E9.0 
date                                                                         
20150505      14246  1729  1064   710   409   268   159   101    78
```

my question is: how do you access the date column in the output table?

does anyone know?

Thanks

Comment: The date is an index. So standard way to access index should work. `df.index`